# Scala: Hash ignores initial size (fast hash table for billions of entries)

Tags: scala, hash, hashmap

I am trying to find out how well Scala's hash functions scale for big hash tables (with billions of entries, e.g. to store how often a particular bit of DNA appeared).

Interestingly, however, both HashMap and OpenHashMap seem to ignore the parameters which specify initial size (2.9.2. and 2.10.0, latest build).

I think that this is so because adding new elements becomes much slower after the first 800.000 or so.

I have tried increasing the entropy in the strings which are to be inserted (only the chars ACGT in the code below), without effect.

Any advice on this specific issue? I would also be grateful to hear your opinion on whether using Scala's inbuilt types is a good idea for a hash table with billions of entries.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{ HashMap, OpenHashMap }    
import scala.util.Random

object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {


        val h = new collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int] {
            override def initialSize = 8388608
        }

        // val h = new scala.collection.mutable.OpenHashMap[Int,Int](8388608); 



        for (i <- 0 until 10000000) {
            val kMer = genkMer()

            if(! h.contains(kMer))
            {
                h(kMer) = 0;
            }
            h(kMer) = h(kMer) + 1;

            if(i % 100000 == 0)
            {
                println(h.size);
            }
        }

        println("Exit. Hashmap size:\n");
        println(h.size);

    }

    def genkMer() : String =
    {
        val nucs = "A" :: "C" :: "G" :: "T" :: Nil

        var s:String = "";
        val r = new scala.util.Random
        val nums = for(i <- 1 to 55 toList) yield r.nextInt(4) 
        for (i <- 0 until 55) {
            s = s + nucs(nums(i))
        }
        s
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you going to run out of memory?

Comment: 32 or 64 bit jvm? about ignoring initial size: it doesnt, you can check the source code for HashMap

Comment: Thanks for your answers. To clarify, this is going to be deployed on machines with 256G+ of RAM.

@Noah: But it will have to copy around bucket content after each doubling, right? But even if this is true, it doesn't explain to me why this drop of performance occurs after 800.000 or so iterations -- I would expect a sharp drop when the rearrangement is carried out, and then a recovery to full speed afterwards.

Comment: @Arjan: 64 bit. Apart from the drop in performance I described, the memory footprint of my program does not change no matter what initial size I set.

Comment: See my update below, you need to increase your max heep size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can't override initialSize, I think scala let's you because it's package private in HashTable:

```
private[collection] final def initialSize: Int = 16
```

Second, if you want to set the initial size, you have to give it a HashTable of the initial size that you want. So there's really no good way of constructing this map without starting at 16, but it does grow by a power of 2, so each resize should get better.

Third, scala collections are relatively slow, I would recommend java/guava/etc collections instead.

Finally, billions of entries is a bit much for most hardware, you'll probably run out of memory. You'll most likely need to use memory mapped files, here's a good example (no hashing though):

https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle

**UPDATE 1**
Here's a good drop in replacement for java collections:

https://github.com/boundary/high-scale-lib

**UPDATE 2**
I ran your code and it did slow down around 800,000 entries, but then I boosted the java heap size and it ran fine. Try using something like this for jvm:

```
-Xmx2G
```

Or, if you want to use every last bit of your memory:

```
-Xmx256G
```

Comment: I don't think high-scale-lib is going to help here.  Not with issues related to map size, anyway.  high-scale-lib gives data structures that perform well even with many CPUs using them concurrently.  I don't think there's anything specific about handling enormous collections.

Comment: How do you think he's going to build a billion entry hashmap? Gotta go multi threaded with a bunch of cpus otherwise it's going to take forever.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use Java data structures to manage a map of billions of entries.  Reasons:

- The max buckets in a Java HashMap is 2^30 (~1B), so

  - with default load factor you'll fail when the map tries to resize after 750 M entries
  - you'll need to use a load factor > 1 (5 would theoretically get you 5 billion items, for example)
  - With a high load factor you're going to get a lot of hash collisions and both read and write performance is going to start to degrade badly
  - Once you actually exceed Integer.MAX_INTEGER values I have no idea what gotchas exist -- .size() on the map wouldn't be able to return the real count, for example
- I would be very worried about running a 256 GB heap in Java -- if you ever hit a full GC it is going lock the world for a long time to check the billions of objects in old gen

If it was me I'd be looking at an off-heap solution: a database of some sort.  If you're just storing (hashcode, count) then one of the many key-value stores out the might work.  The biggest hurdle is finding one that can support many billions of records (some max out at 2^32).

If you can accept some error, probabilistic methods might be worth looking at.  I'm no expert here, but the stuff listed [here](http://www.bro-ids.org/development/projects/counting.html) sounds relevant.

Answer (score 2):

These are the wrong data structures. You will hit a ram limit pretty fast (unless you have 100+gb, and even then you will still hit limits very fast).

I don't know if suitable data structures exist for scala, although someone will have done something with Java probably.